# Regex to trim text within double quotes

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I would like a regex which will remove extra white space at the beginning and end of elements of text which are in double quotes. Currently I'm failing to come up with one which works though.

eg. Transform

Martin said " oogle booogle" and Martha said " totty wottie "

to

Martin said "oogle booogle" and Martha said "totty wottie"

Thanks,

Mark

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to use a simple regex such as `/"\s*(.*?)\s*"/` and replace with `"$1"`.

**Explanation of regex:**

- `"` - a litteral `"` character
- `\s*` - Space/tab/newline characters repeated 0 or more times
- `(.*?)` - A lazy capturing group matching as little as possible until it reaches the next part:
- `\s*` - Space/tab/newline characters repeated 0 or more times
- `"` - a litteral `"` character

**Code**:

```
<?php
    $string = 'Martin said " oogle booogle" and Martha said " totty wottie "';
    $string = preg_replace('/"\s*(.*?)\s*"/', '"$1"', $string);
    var_dump($string);
    //string(58) "Martin said "oogle booogle" and Martha said "totty wottie""
?>
```

[**Demo**](http://codepad.org/Izswvwk7)

Answer (score 0):

```
$string = 'Martin said " oogle booogle" and Martha said " totty wottie "';

$str = preg_replace_callback(
    '/"(.*?)"/',
    function ($matches) {
        return '"' . trim($matches[1]) . '"';
    },
    $string
);

var_dump($str);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$a = 'Martin said " oogle booogle" and Martha said " totty wottie "';
function Replace1($M){
  //print_r($M);
  return "\"".trim($M[1])."\"";
}
$new=preg_replace_callback("#\"[ ]*(.*?)[ ]*\"#","Replace1",' '.$a.' ');
echo($new);
```

output

```
Martin said "oogle booogle" and Martha said "totty wottie"
```

Answer (score 0):

While the answer provided by Mark Baker will work, I think it's a bit overcomplicated.  You don't need a callback for this, a simple `preg_replace` will do:

```
$string = 'Martin said " oogle booogle" and Martha said " totty wottie "';
$str = preg_replace('/"\s*(.*?)\s*"/', '"$1"', $string);
```